# Rest DELETE Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, extjs, http-delete

Can u explain me why DELETE method (store.remove() in Edit.js) throws 400 Bad request. Other method works well. In header request url seems to be ok "http://localhost:8080/Diary/rest/notes/22?_dc=1461837327580".

I know that problem is in payload of DELETE method, store.remove() includes ID as payload. How can i disable that and send DELETE method without body, because ID is already in URL

Rest Service

```
@Path("/notes")
public class NoteRestService {
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;



private NoteDaoImpl noteDao = new NoteDaoImpl();
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getNotes(){
    String login = request.getSession(true).getAttribute("login").toString();
    List<Note> notes = noteDao.getUserNotes(login);
    return new Gson().toJson(notes);
}

@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response postNote(Note note){
    String login = request.getSession(true).getAttribute("login").toString();
    note.setUser(login);
    noteDao.persist(note);
    URI noteUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(Long.toString(note.getId())).build();
    return Response.created(noteUri).build();
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response updateNote(@PathParam("id") String id,Note note){
    String login = request.getSession(true).getAttribute("login").toString();
    Note editNote = noteDao.getNote(Long.parseLong(id));
    note.setCreated(editNote.getCreated());
    note.setUser(login);
    noteDao.update(note);
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public Response deleteNote(@PathParam("id") String id){
    Note note = noteDao.getNote(Long.valueOf(id));
    if (note==null){
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    noteDao.delete(Long.parseLong(id));
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
}
```

EditController.js

```
Ext.define('MVC.controller.Edit', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


init: function () {
    this.control({
        'editForm > button#SaveRecord': {
            click: this.onSaveButtonClick
        },
        'editForm > button#DeleteButton': {
            click: this.onDeleteButtonClick
        }
    });
},

onSaveButtonClick: function (btn) {
    //get reference to the form
    var detailView = btn.up('editForm');

    //get the form inputs
    var data = detailView.getValues();

    //see if the record exists
    var store = Ext.getStore('TestStore');
    console.log(data.id);
    var record = store.getById(data.id);

    if (!record) {
        record = Ext.create('MVC.model.Note', {
            title: data.title,
            created: new Date(),
            updated: new Date(),
            text: data.text
        });
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Created', data.title);

        store.insert(0, record);
        store.sync();
        return;
    }

    record.set(data);

    store.sync();
    //manually update the record
    detailView.updateRecord();
},

onDeleteButtonClick: function (btn) {

    //get reference to the form
    var detailView = btn.up('editForm');

    //get the form inputs
    var data = detailView.getValues();

    var store = Ext.getStore('TestStore');
    var record = store.getById(data.id);
    store.remove(record);
    store.sync();
}
});
```

**UPD: Store**

```
Ext.define('MVC.store.TestStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MVC.model.Note'
],

storeId: 'TestStore',
model: 'MVC.model.Note',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'rest/notes',
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'GET',
        update: 'PUT',
        destroy:' DELETE'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post your store and proxy config?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a *HttpMethod.DELETE* with a body.

This is not explicitly stated in the RFC, but some Proxy servers will reject the body if you have one in a *delete* method. Spring lowers the standard and will reject your query with a **Bad Request**.

Remove the body as well as the answer to fix your issue.

Check this for more information:
[Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Answer (score 0):

If TestStore is the store you're using, I'd guess that your problem is here:

> ```
> actionMethods: {
>     create: 'POST',
>     read: 'GET',
>     update: 'PUT',
>     destroy: 'GET'
> },
> ```

I don't recognize the @DELETE annotation, so I'm not 100% sure but if your controller is expecting DELETE, and you're sending GET, that could explain the 400 error.

Comment: No, i've changed DELETE to GET because of that problem.  With GET it works, but if there will be DELETE it would not.

Comment: Maybe a bug with writeAllFields.  Have you tried removing that to see if that fixed the delete problem?